# fullcreen video overlay link in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, html5-video, fullscreen

Hello I have overlay over video. I used this code and it worked well.

```
#overlay {
   position: absolute;
   top: 100px;
   font-size: 20px;
   background-color: black;
   width: 100px;
   z-index: 2147483647;;
}


<div id="overlay">This is <a  target="_blank" href="http://google.com"> HTML </a></div>
```

But in last version of chrome I can see my overlay div but I cant click the link in fullscreen mode. Have you got some idea? I tried to force the fullsceen lower z-index but it doesnt work:

```
:-webkit-full-screen {
    z-index: 2147483640 !important;
}
```